# How to use Canon LiDE 70 scanner with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, scanner, canon-lide

I have used my Canon LiDE 70 scanner with the Canon Toolbox software on Windows Vista. Now I have installed Windows 7.

I downloaded a driver and installed it when I connected the scanner. But it was just a driver, so I don't have any scanner software.

I would like to scan a document to a PDF if possible. Is there any software I can use with my scanner available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/).  It is very good for working with all kinds of images.  Simply open it up and go to

> File -> Acquire -> From Scanner or
>   Camera...

To create PDFs from Paint.NET or any or other program, I recommend [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/).

I use both of these on Windows 7 and they work very well.  They are free of charge.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: no canon toobox and the buttons didn't work.  I called canon, and they directed me to this scanner to download the toolbox, which I installed and it is working just like it used to.

http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/scanners/canoscan_series/canoscan_8600f#DriversAndSoftware

Answer (score 0):

According to the Windows Compatibility Center (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Search.aspx?l=en-us&type=Hardware&s=Canon%20LiDE%2070) this scanner is compatible with Windows 7. Have you tried just downloading the software directly from Canon? Although more times than not, you should be able to just plug it in and start using it.